# TLD pointing to subdomain of TLD connected to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, nginx, rack

I'm trying to point the root of of `domain2.com` to a subdomain of `domain1.com` (which is pointing to a Heroku instance). Do I need to run some kind of reverse proxy for this to work? If so, what kind of config do I need? (can i use `rack-reverse-proxy` or will I need to set up haproxy or nginx or something?)

I've tried just simply CNAMEing `domain2.com` to `x.domain1.com` and adding `domain2.com` to my heroku instance. This, as expected, just brings me to `domain1.com`.

Thanks!

Comment: Are these all custom domains on the same app? Have you set up routes for the new subdomain?

Comment: Yes, I have a regex match for them in my routes.rb, the subdomains work, just not the additional customer domain/s pointed to them.